# What https status code to use when user has access to url but not to query parameters?

Tags: security, http, permissions, status

Good day,

What http status code should be used when the requester has access to that url but had improper query parameters.

Let's say something like this:

As user 100, I can access http://example.com/bankaccount/get?id=100

However, I should not be able to see the bank account of another user, let's say via http://example.com/bankaccount/get?id=200 .

Which HTTP Status code should be used?

Comment: Why do you need to specify the ID anyway if you already know the user’s ID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the access is forbidden, return [403](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.4):

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. […] If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity.  If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.

But I don’t see the point of explicitly specifying the ID anyway as you already now the user’s ID. So `/bankaccount/get` should suffice in this case.

Comment: What do you mean? That the server should not specify that it's 403 because of invalid id? ....but still not 404? Pardon, just trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: @Franz See: You should either use 403 and describe the cause of the error if you want to let the users know it or use 404 without specifying the cause. But as you already know the user’s ID, you don’t need to specify the ID in the URL at all. So just `/bankaccount/get` would suffice and you use the user’s ID that you already have internally.

Comment: But what if (for another example) you're a group administrator that has access to several bank accounts (which means an id parameter is needed), and you accessed a bank account that is not under your group.

Comment: @Franz See: If the access is forbidden, return 403. If the access if forbidden but you don’t want to let the user know it, return 404.

Answer (score 1):

In your example I would either send a 302, redirecting him to an error page, or a 200 with a custom error page right there. This will be the most user friendly version.

Edit:
If you want to opt for something in the 4xx area of status codes, make sure the webserver supplies an appropriate error page. The average user will not be happy to see a white screen with "403 - Forbidden". 403 with a custom error page is a good solution to this problem.

Comment: @artbristol: Thanks for asking, that's what I suggested in a comment to another response. I will update my answer to include this option which is of course valid as well.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for 403 - Forbidden, since it's a legitimate request, but not allowed for the current user.

If the query parameter names were wrong, on the other hand, it should probably be 404.

Comment: 400 is rather for malformed syntax.

Comment: That's what I meant - eg. if the url ended /get?zz=100 instead of /get?id=100

Comment: But that URL is not malformed. It’s rather not known to the server or cannot be understood.

Comment: If you really opt for something in the 4xx area of status codes, make sure the webserver supplies an appropriate error page. The average user will not be happy to see a white screen with "403 - Forbidden".